# Can't fetch data from SQLite database in AS

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating a Quiz app in Android Studio, and so I created a Database that contains the questions. In the helper class I have a method getAllQuestions that transfers the questions from the database to an array list, so then I can extract the Questions in Main and setText in Buttons. However, while I run my app the buttons and the Question are empty, without the app throwing exceptions like nullpointer if the list itself was empty.
[image: The Screenshot]

DB_Helper methods:

private void addQuestions(QuestionsDataBase Questions)
{

```
    ContentValues cv =  new ContentValues();
    cv.put(QuestionTable.Column_Question,Questions.getQuestion());
    cv.put(QuestionTable.Column_Option1,Questions.getOption1());
    cv.put(QuestionTable.Column_Option2,Questions.getOption2());
    cv.put(QuestionTable.Column_Option3,Questions.getOption3());
    cv.put(QuestionTable.Column_Option4,Questions.getOption4());
    cv.put(QuestionTable.Column_Correct_Ans,Questions.getQuestion());
    db.insert(QuestionTable.Table_Name,null,cv);
}
```

public  ArrayList getAllQuestions(){

```
    ArrayList<QuestionsDataBase> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] Projection ={
            QuestionTable._ID,
            QuestionTable.Column_Question,
            QuestionTable.Column_Option1,
            QuestionTable.Column_Option2,
            QuestionTable.Column_Option3,
            QuestionTable.Column_Option4,
            QuestionTable.Column_Correct_Ans
    };
    Cursor c = db.query(QuestionTable.Table_Name,
            Projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            QuestionsDataBase questions = new QuestionsDataBase();
            questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Question)));
            questions.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option1)));
            questions.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option2)));
            questions.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option3)));
            questions.setOption4(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option4)));
            questions.setCorrectAns(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Correct_Ans)));
            questionsList.add(questions);
            questionsList.add(questions);

        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return questionsList;
}
```

Methods in MainActivity:

private void fecthDB(){

```
    DB_Helper db = new DB_Helper(this);
    questionList = db.getAllQuestions();
    startQuiz();
}
```

private void startQuiz()
{

```
    questionTotalCount = questionList.size(); // the total amount of questions in the current quizactivity( is set to 10)
    Collections.shuffle(questionList); // shuffle the questions form the database that are stored in QuestionList
    showQuestions();

    nextbutton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if(!answered){
            if(option1.isChecked() || option2.isChecked() || option3.isChecked() || option4.isChecked())
                QuizOperations();
        }
    });

}
```

private void showQuestions() // Showing the question and the options from database
{

```
    rbGroup.clearCheck();
    if(questionCounter< questionTotalCount) // if not all the questions yet answered set text to new questions
    {
        currentQuestions = questionList.get(questionCounter);
        questionCount.setText(currentQuestions.getQuestion());
        option1.setText(currentQuestions.getOption1());
        option2.setText(currentQuestions.getOption2());
        option3.setText(currentQuestions.getOption3());
        option4.setText(currentQuestions.getOption4());

        questionCounter ++; // +1 to question counter
        answered = false; // tye quiz is not yet completely answered while the current question is smaller then total
        nextbutton.setText("Next");

        questionCount.setText("Questions: " + questionCounter + "/" + questionTotalCount); // how many questions answered out of 10
    }
    else{// if all the questions are answered
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QuizActivity.class); // open the next activity

        }, 500); // wait for a half second
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to set other fields on your `QuestionsDataBase` object here rather than `setQuestion()` for each column in the database query:

```
            questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option1)));
            questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option2)));
            questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option3)));
            questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Option4)));
            questions.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuestionTable.Column_Correct_Ans)));
```

> Thanks, edited it. Now it shows the options, but doesn't show the question itself.

You are setting text to `questionCount` twice where the later overwrites the first one. Maybe the first one should set the question textview instead.

Comment: Thanks, edited it. Now it shows the options, but doesn't show the question itself.

Comment: updated with another problem in your code